# CakePHP 3 ODBC connection

Tags: php, database, cakephp, pdo, odbc

Using Windev our databases are currently hosted on HFSQL, the proprietary Windev database system.

I would like to use CakePHP to allow a web view of the data.

I know how to connect to the HFSQL database via ODBC and it works in php, but impossible through CakePHP, even when trying to create a new driver.

Would anyone have a track?

Thank you in advance.

Have a good day.

Brice.

Comment: Hello,
I tried to start the SQLSERVER driver to modify it and allow the connection in ODBC, but this is beyond my knowledge and generates a lot of errors:

SQLSTATE[HY09]: <<Unknown error>>: 0 Que s'est-il pass� ? Erreur dans le code SQL de la requ�te <SQLODBC>. Initialisation de la requ�te impossible. Fichier objects inconnu Erreur d�tect�e : FROM sys.>>>>[objects]<<<< T Code erreur : 28000002 Niveau : erreur fatale (EL_FA (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)

I will contact CakeDC for the cost of developing the driver.

Thank you for the answer.

Have a good day.